# Using Ajax to delete a database row only deletes the first row, not the selected row

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm using the code below to loop through my database rows and display the info. Each form has a delete button that should delete that row from the database :

```
function show_scheduled_tweets () {
    global $wpdb;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM wp_tweettweet";
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_A);

    foreach($results as $result) {
        $tweet2 =  $result[text];
        $recycleOption = $result[recycle];
        $id = $result[id];
    ?>

        <form id="tweet-<?php echo $id; ?>" class="tweetclass form-inline" action="" method="post">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="recycle" <?php if($recycleOption == 1){ echo "checked";} ?>>Recycle Tweet?
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="tweet" value="<?php echo $tweet2; ?>"></div>
            <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="tweetdate"></div>
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
            <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="timepicker" class="timepicker"/></div>
            <input class="tweetsubmit" type="submit" value="Save">
            <input class="tweetdelete" type="submit" value="delete">
        </form>
    <?php
    }
}
show_scheduled_tweets();
```

Here is my Ajax :

```
jQuery('.tweetdelete').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = jQuery('input[name="id"]').val();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: {
            'action': 'db_tables_delete',
            'id': id
        },
          beforeSend: function() {
              alert('before')
          },
          success: function(){
              alert('success')
          },
          error: function(){
              alert('error')
          },
    });
});
```

Let's say I have five different rows of data showing. Now matter which delete button I click, the top row will always be deleted. In other words, if I click the delete button for row 3, the first row will be deleted.

Comment: You didn't post your delete query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your current code **[`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/)** returns value of first element. Check the [description from documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val/) :

> Get the current value of the first element in the set of matched elements or set the value of every matched element.

---

You need to get the `id` value based on clicked element, use **[`prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevall/)**

```
var id = jQuery(this).prevAll('input[name="id"]').val();
```

---

or **[`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)** method

```
var id = jQuery(this).siblings('input[name="id"]').val();
```

---

or with **[`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)**(or **[`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)**) and **[`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)**

```
var id = jQuery(this).closest('form').find('input[name="id"]').val();
```

Comment: Ahh ok I see. Because, the current way is just select the first id in the list of forms, correct?

Comment: @user715564 : yes `val()` returns value of first element from the selector

Answer (score 0):

Your selector for the US is not particular to the tweet in the firm. The event passed to the JS function will carry with it a target (which will be the button that was clicked), if you echo your $id into a data attribute of that button then the relevant id it will be accessible within the target:

```
<input data-id="<?php echo $id;?>" class="tweetdelete" type="submit" value="delete">
```

and in your JS:

```
var id = jQuery(event.target).attr('data-id');
```